# Is it possible to append the metrics label value before/ after scraping to a different value?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I have a use case where I need to append metrics label value in Prometheus.
for eg, if my metrics has a label {pod=pod1}, I need to change it to {pod=pod2} before or after scraping. Is this supported?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a look at those two prometheus configurations :

1. [relabel_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config) : this will allow you to work with the labels name and value **before** the scrape
2. [metric_relabel_configs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#metric_relabel_configs) : this will allow you to work with your labels **after** the scrape *(but before ingestion)*

You can check out this [article](https://www.robustperception.io/relabel_configs-vs-metric_relabel_configs) which explains a bit more the difference between those two.